# How to make a pie chart that sorts by IP address subnet in kibana4.5

Tags: sorting, ip, kibana, subnet, cidr

I have a search that returns a list of IP addresses. I would like to create a pie chart in kibana where the inner slices are defined by CIDR masks (e.g. x.y.z.0/24) and the outer slices divide each subnet into the IP addresses that were returned (e.g. x.y.z.24, x.y.z.37, x.y.z.103) would be divisions of that inner slice.

Currently, I know how to do this using IPv4 range, and manually typing in the sub-nets I'm looking for, but as the data changes from day to day, I would like something that automatically recognizes the subnets and sorts IPs like this.

If this is not possible, is there anything that is similar, where using kibana I can sort IPs by subnet?